# How I can divide values in a column by specific row in Python?

Tags: python

I have a tab file and I want to divide features(upstream,downstrs,downupst,annotate or ...) of a gene to standard feature. 
last two columns are the result columns for cond_a and cond_b that I want to produce.
I was writing a code to be able to save each line in a tuple and then search tuples and do the divisions but it was confusing for me.
How can I do this in Python?

```
for line in open(myfile,"r").readlines():
    Fld = line.strip().split("\t")
    gene,feature,cond_a,cond_b= Fld[0],Fld[1],int(Fld[2]),int(Fld[3])

gene feature  cond_a cond_b     
A   upstream    2      5    2/5   5/8
A   standard    5      8    5/5   8/8
C   standard    4      23   4/4   23/23
D   downstrs    3      1    3/9   1/5
D   standard    9      5    9/9   5/5
H   standard    2      9    2/2   9/9
H   downupst    1      2    1/2   2/9
H   annotate    4      8    4/2   8/9
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear how the last two rows are expected to be calculated. Also, please show what you have attempted for the calculation so far

Comment: each gene has only one standard feature, but it can has many other features as well, my goal is dividing other features (non standards, they could have any names) of the gene to standard. I know how to do it in R, but I had no idea how I could do it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want (for future reference it's best to leave out technical details that are field-related and not programming related - makes it easier for those of us who know nothing about genes to help), and I can't tell how you're calculating those two columns exactly.  However, this looks like a job for Pandas.  You would do a simple example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'gene':['A', 'C', 'D'], 'cond_a':[2,3,4], 'cond_b':[5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_col'] = df['cond_a'] / df['cond_b']
```

For your data you would load it in with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter='/t')
```

However you're calculating your other columns, you can do it pretty easily with Pandas.  Additionally you can groupby various categories to work on subsets, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but this is not what I want to calculate, lets make the question clear, first 2/5 is dividing first row(2) to second row(5) (standard of gene A). 5/5 is division to itself because it is standard which is 1. last row (4/2) is dividing last row to row number 6
    A_____upstream_____2_____2/5
    A_____standard_____5_____5/5
    C_____standard_____4_____4/4
    D_____downstrs____3_____3/9
    D_____standard_____9_____9/9
    H_____standard_____2_____2/2
    H_____downupst____1_____1/2
    H_____annotate_____4_____4/2

Comment: Kindly explain the question clearly, in H_____standard_____2_____2/2 why dividing 2/2 why not 2/1, and the next sentence why 1/2 why not 1/4?

Comment: thanks, it is standard itself and needs to be divided to itself which is equal to 1. If we only have gene H, I want to divide non standards to standard within that gene. This is showing divisions for gene H: H_____downupst____1 should be divided to H_____standard_____2  H_____downupst____1 should be divided to H_____standard_____2 H_____standard_____2 should be divided to H_____standard_____2

Comment: H_____downupst____1 should be divided to H_____standard_____2  (1/2)

Comment: H_____annotate_____4 should be divided to H_____standard_____2 (4/2)

Comment: H_____standard_____2 should be divided to H_____standard_____2 (2/2)

Comment: there are more than 2000 genes, there are only one standard per gene but there could be more than 10 non-standard features per gene

Comment: are the gene sorted?

Comment: Not really, they are not sorted

Comment: are you using excel or csv to get the input. can you share it?

Comment: it is a big tab deliminated file that I can not upload it.  This a portion of the data:

Comment: ACT1---down3ss---1 ###
RPL39---down3ss---1 ### 
ACT1---down3ss---1  ###
TAN1---down3ss---3 ###
TAN1---up5ss---4 ###
RPL28---down5ss---7### 
TAN1---up5ss---9 ###
RPL28---down5ss---17 ### 
RPL39---up5ss---28 ###
TAN1---up3ss---46 ###
TAN1---down3ss---53 ###
TAN1---standard---331 ###
ACT1---standard---25329 ###
RPL39---standard---41638 ###
RPL28---standard---115770 ###

Comment: Please explain the *pattern* involved here, preferably without trying to explain the genetics.  For a pseudocode example, "if feature == standard: calculate cond_a divided by cond_b for <something else>"